# "Save to all networks" (for profile) didn't apply to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

I updated my profile a bit ago. At the time I saved with the option to apply it to all communities.

However I just noticed it doesn't appear to have applied to Stack Exchange.

I'd rather not toot my horn too much, but the URL schemes where it worked are:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/users/{user_id}/{username}?tab=profile`
- `https://math.stackexchange.com/users/{user_id}/{username}?tab=profile`
- `https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/{user_id}/{username}?tab=profile`

Compared to SE:

- `https://stackexchange.com/users/{user_id}/{username}?tab=profile`

Any reason this would have failed? It seems like a bug to me.